# How do I correctly use enum in this C++ example?

Tags: c++, enums

I have a class something like this with a public enum declared:

```
// DataStorage.h
class DataStorage
{    
  enum ActionType { ADD, REMOVE };

  public :
    data();
    void update(ActionType action, Data dataItem);
};
```

And then I have a Main.cc that uses it like so ...

```
// Main.cc
#include "DataStorage.h"

int main() {
  DataStorage dataStorage;
  Data dataItem("abc123");
  dataStorage.update(ActionType.ADD, dataItem); <<-- error here
}
```

My problem is when I compile I get this error:

```
Main.cc:29:18: error: ‘ActionType’ was not declared in this scope
```

What am I doing wrong?  Where should the enum be declared and how should I use it in main?

Thx!

Comment: `ActionType` is a part of `DataStorage`, not global.

Comment: @chris Do I move the 'enum ActionType...' so it's above the 'class DataStorage' line to make it global?  Is that all I need to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code should work (and is perfectly fine by means of *c++ standards*):

```
// DataStorage.h
class DataStorage
{    
  public :
    enum ActionType { ADD, REMOVE };

    data();
    void update(ActionType action, Data dataItem);
};
```

---

```
  dataStorage.update(DataStorage::ADD, dataItem);
```

If you want to refer the enum values using the `ActionType` identifier, use the new [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)   [`enum class`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) feature (would resolve to `DataStorage::ActionType::ADD` then).

Comment: I think I got it working like your code but I had to do `dataStorage.update(DataStorage::ADD, dataItem);` which seems wrong because it should be `ActionType::ADD`, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 4):

update

```
dataStorage.update(ActionType.ADD, dataItem);
```

to:

```
dataStorage.update(DataStorage::ADD, dataItem);
```

Note: `You need to make enum type ActionType public`.

```
class DataStorage
{ 
public :   
    enum ActionType { ADD, REMOVE };

    data();
    void update(ActionType action, Data dataItem);
};
```

Comment: Or to `DataStorage::ActionType::ADD` in case you declare it as `enum class` or compiling with MSVC and you dont care about being standart conform

Comment: **Note:** `ActionType` isn't `public`!

Comment: @Paranaix Thx, I'm new to this so if you could tell me what would be the correct "standard" way of doing this, that would be great, thx!

Comment: @RobertHume Just as billz posted it. `enum` adds its symbols/values in the enclosing namespace and doesnt define a namespace on its own. Therefor the symbols (`ADD` & `REMOVE`) are in the namespace of `DataStorage` here. Thats completely right. MSVC however adds an extension allowing you to threat enums like they have namespaces on their own. With c++11 these extensions became actually quite useless as `enum class` was introduced, not just providing enums with strong typing but also giving them a own namespace.

Comment: @Paranaix That explains all the missing points pretty well :)!